# Meaning of random.nextInt(12*4+2)

Tags: java, random

so once again we were given code bites we should use and this one I don't really get the sense of:

```
int r = random.nextInt(12*4+2)
```

Is there any difference to
`random.nextInt(50)` ? I'm a bit confused...

Comment: No, there is no difference between the two. I believe the first one is more *verbose* to the developer.

Comment: No, no semantic difference at all. However, there may be some meaning to seeing it as `12*4+2` rather than just `50`. For example, `86400` looks like a strange, meaningless number - but `24 * 60 * 60` is (more) obviously the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: Wow, that went quick! Thanks a lot, this is supposed to generate card-IDs from a 12*4 color and 2 black cards. I suppose I have to give each generated number a meaning.

Answer (score 2):

`12 * 4 + 2` is a compile-time evaluable *constant expression*.

It's exactly equivalent to `50`, but the former might be adopted for readability.

`random#nextInt(n)` draws a uniformly distributed random integer in [0, n).

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) of `random.nextInt()`

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

There is no difference between this two expressions

```
int r = random.nextInt(12*4+2)
random.nextInt(50)
```

Since

```
int r = random.nextInt(12*4+2)
```

will be evaluated as

```
int tmp = 12*4+2;
int r = random.nextInt(tmp);
```